# Range query for long type in aws elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, range-query

I am trying to query an elasticsearch index in AWS to get all entries with a mass attribute greater than 1000, the datatype for the attribute is Long.

I found the range query and have tried that (see example below) but it's returning nothing but when I use other queries they return attributes with mass greater than 1000 so they're definitely in the index.

This is the Range query I'm trying:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "index": "users",
  "type": "user",
  "path": "_search?filter_path=filter",
  "body": {
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":[{
                "range": {
                  "mass": {
                    "gte": 1000
                  }
                }
            }]
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any error messages, just zero hits.

Comment: Are there more bool clauses under the bool element or why do you put that single range query inside a boolean query?

Comment: There aren't, I've tried without the bool (just having the range part) and that didn't work either

Comment: For me it looks like you are using the wrong HTTP verb. Use **GET** instead of POST.

Comment: Just tried that, also got zero hits

Comment: Remove the *filter_path* parameter. With that parameter you control what should be included in the response.

Comment: Yes! That's working now, do you know of anywhere I can find details of this path parameter for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem that's causing to get you zero hits is the **filter_path** parameter you specify in

```
"path": "_search?filter_path=filter"
```

As stated in the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html) the filter_path parameter is part of the common options regarding the REST API's. That means you can always add that parameter.

With Response Filtering you can reduce the response returned by Elasticsearch. Since you defined

```
_search?filter_path=filter
```

you probably get zero hits because there is no filter-element that can be returned.